# Как поместить свою библиотеку в jar файл программы в командной строке

Tags: java, jar

Пытаюсь разобраться в том как поместить собственную библиотеку в создаваемый jar файл программы.
Понимаю что для данных целей лучше использовать Maven и подобные полезные вещи, но хочется разораться как это именно в командной строке делатся.

Из поисков в интернете нашел намеки на то что в манифесте нужно указывать пути подгрузки библиотек, а их самих помещать в проект например в папку lib, но более подробной информации так и не смог найти.

Comment: jar это такая же консольная утилита как и tar, например, т.е. она по сути пакует файлы в архив. Просто перечисляете какие файлы в архив положить и всё. Будет ли это работать? это уже другой вопрос и для ответа на него надо почитать и про манифест файл, и про classpath и прочее прочее.

Comment: Можете начать с документации к утилите jar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым.
В директории где лежит манифест я создал папку lib и в нее поместил свою библиотеку.
Затем прописал в манифесте:

```
Class-Path: lib\YourLibrary.jar
```

И чтобы при создании jar архива в него добавилась папка lib помимо основного пакета самой программы так же написал её в конце команды создания архива:

```
jar -cmf manifest.txt MyProgramm.jar com lib
```

В результате необходимая для программы библиотека теперь всегда будет в комплекте.